# wince data misalignment

Tags: c++, windows-ce

While running a program on a wince 5.0 arm device emulator, it always reports a data misalignment. The exception is like

```
Data Abort: Thread=8db5e6f4 Proc=8c24cb60 'test.exe'
AKY=00001001
PC=03f91cfc(coredll.dll+0x00021cfc)
RA=1a12a988(test.exe+0x0011a988)
BVA=0000001e
FSR=00000001
```

According to the map file, the PC is in function `CeHeapCreate()`. The return address is not in the code section, maybe in the heap.
When running application verifier to detect the memory problem, the data abort disappears and the program runs normally.
What causes it and how to debug this case?

Answer (score 1):

We'd need to see the call into coredll that test.exe is making.  The return address (RA) tells you where in your app the call is coming from, you just have to [decode it back to a line of code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sloh/archive/2005/02/28/381706.aspx).  A WAG is that you're passing a struct or byte array into an API call that is unaligned.  Again, without code, we can only guess.

Comment: The total length of code and data sections is around 0xB0000. So the RA 0x11a988 is beyond that address space. When I make some code changes, the data abort can disappear for a while, but appear again in another place.

Comment: How about statics?  They are allocated in a separate location.